# Calculate first difference based on ID and year in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with observations from 2010 until 2019 for all 51 Us States and various columns. One of the columns is Gdp. The dataset looks like this:

```
State    year  ...   GDP
Alabama  2010  ...   182.26
Alabama  2011  ...   185.05
.        .     .    .
.        .     .    .
.        .     .    .
Alaska   2010  ...   54.15
Alaska   2011  ...   54.65
```

I would like to calculate the first diferrence of GDP (year_t - year_(t-1)) for all years and all states. Does somebody know how I can do this?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = c(NA, diff(GDP)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to @YuriySaraykin dplyr-based answer:

#### Base R

```r
dat$Diff <- ave(dat$GDP, dat$State, FUN = function(z) c(NA, diff(z)))
dat
#     State year    GDP Diff
# 1 Alabama 2010 182.26   NA
# 2 Alabama 2011 185.05 2.79
# 6  Alaska 2010  54.15   NA
# 7  Alaska 2011  54.65 0.50
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, Diff := c(NA, diff(GDP)), by = .(State)]
```

(same output, though as a `data.table`)

---

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alaska", "Alaska"), year = c("2010", "2011", "2010", "2011"), GDP = c(182.26, 185.05, 54.15, 54.65), Diff = c(NA, 2.79000000000002, NA, 0.5)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```